# How to create a summary report that contains other reports?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have 4 reports that I run for 8 different environments. Each report creates a graph from some usage tables. It's very simple SQL that creates a very simple graph.

The guy who used to do these manually took the results of each one of these reports and pasted them into a powerpoint doc.

I have been able to get each one of these reports into report server so you just need need to click on the report and see the graph. I can set up subscriptions to send out these results with no problem either.

The problem is that I am sure the managers don't want 32 graphs coming their way. They want only one doc to see all the graphs.

Is there a way to put all these graphs on one report?

Comment: I'm no expert on SSRS, but I am not sure if you can create a combination of these reports without creating a new, dashboard report (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/72651/).  Just my take on it, but somebody with more BI experience might be able to give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.  You can create a single report that has multiple data sources (one per environment).  Add the data sets required.  Recreate the graphs (you may be able to leverage some cut-and-paste).  In order to format them nicely, you will need to place the graphs into the cells of a matrix.

You could also build a single report that links to other reports.

I realize this is a high-level description of how to do it - if you need further details, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to do this.  The first is to do what JHFB said and to create different report objects that hit different data sets.  The second is to create individual reports for each report item, then add those reports to an all-encompassing report using subreports.

The main advantage to breaking the reports out is that you can then pick just one single report to look at.  If you don't need that, then just create the reports in one single report using multiple data sets.